# Hive query string case

Tags: string, select, hive, case

Is there a way to get all the types of string cases while doing this:

```
select count(word) from table where word="abcd"
```

Actually when doing this, it is not the same as this:

```
select count(word) from table where word="ABCD"
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Ignoring the case in a where clause is very simple. You can, for example, convert both sides of the comparison to all caps notation:

```
SELECT COUNT(word) 
FROM   table 
WHERE  UPPER(word)=UPPER('ABCD')
```

Regardless of the capitalization used for the search term , the UPPER function makes them match as desired.

Answer (score 5):

```
select count(word) from table where lower(word)="abcd"
```

However this assumes it's not a partitioned table. If it's partitioned by word you would start doing a full table scan because of the "lower("

Answer (score 1):

SELECT count(word)  FROM table
WHERE   word   RLIKE
"(?i)WOrd1|wOrd2"